# Can I connect to local windows service application with secure WebSocket (wss)

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, websocket, service

Can I connect to local windows service application (c#) with secure WebSocket (wss)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

The URL to which to connect; this should be the URL to which the WebSocket server will respond. This should use the URL scheme wss://, **although some software may allow you to use the insecure ws:// for local connections.**

Comment: `Can I connect to local windows service application (c#) with secure WebSocket (wss)` - yes, as long as your local windows service application is configured to do so

Comment: I got an error when I try wss my new post is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220221/calling-c-sharp-socket-service-from-javascript-with-security-websocket-wss

Answer (score 0):

i solve

```
X509Certificate oCertificate = CertificateKontrol.GetCertificate();

 public class CertificateKontrol
    {
        public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
        {
            try
            {                        
                byte[] barySertifika = global::EImzaAt.Properties.Resources.cert;
                using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(barySertifika))
                {
                    return new X509Certificate2(ReadStream(stream), pwd);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                throw new System.Exception("err");
            }
        }

        private static byte[] ReadStream(Stream input)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```