# Calling c# socket service from JavaScript with security WebSocket (wss)

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket, tcpclient

in JavaScript i call local windows TCPClient service (c#)

```
var url = 'wss://127.0.0.1:6372';
var oWebSocket = new WebSocket(url); // error
```

in server

```
serverCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificate, "pwd");
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
listener.Start();
while (true)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client to connect...");
     TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
     ProcessClientS(client);
}

static void ProcessClientS(TcpClient client)
{
      SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);
      // Authenticate the server but don't require the client to authenticate.
      try
      {
         sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls12, true); //error line
```

in server side I get "A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception." and "An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate"
in client side I get " Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID"

How can I pass local certificate to my server

Comment: your ssl certificate is invalid

Comment: yes it is. CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority

Comment: not according to the error

Comment: SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate));

Comment: public static bool ValidateServerCertificateX(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)

Comment: certificate is null

Comment: I guess your question is how to set up SSL on whatever your server platform is then

Comment: i dont think in chorem security tab

Comment: This page is secure (valid HTTPS).
Certificate - valid and trusted
The connection to this site is using a valid, trusted server certificate issued by COMODO RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA.
View certificate
Connection - secure connection settings
The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using TLS 1.2, ECDHE_RSA with P-384, and AES_256_GCM.
Resources - all served securely
All resources on this page are served securely.

Comment: I have purchased a valid ssl certificate but the error message is the same. I thing javascript websocket object can't sent my ssl certificate to server